# strange bug when i rotate the screen the listview inside of viewpager will disappear

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

ok I have a very strange bug! when I rotate the screen for two times the listview inside viewPager will disappear but that only happen when I change the context of viewPager which is a listView (but as I said its work ok when I rotate for the first time and its ok when I don't change the viewpager by pressing on a radioGroup):

I think the problem should be either when I change the adapter inside viewpager by radio group
(I mean this code):

```
myViewpager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManag, false));
myViewpager.setCurrentItem(200);
```

or with listview inside the fragment (which viewAdapter) use:
(this code):

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_in_money_manager, parent, false);
    }

    TextView category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1x);
    TextView amount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2x);

    category.setText(categoryArray[position]);
    amount.setText(amountArray[position] + MoneyManager.DOLLAR);

    if (expanseB[position]) {
        amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF4444"));
    } else {
        amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
    }
    return row;
}
```

Any suggestion would be greatful :)

Here are all the codes :

```
public class MoneyManager extends FragmentActivity implements FragmentChangeMoneyDialog.Communicator, OnCheckedChangeListener {

    // ...some def
    FragmentMoneyTotal frgTotalListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ...some def

            radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            // Create a ViewPager
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragManag = getSupportFragmentManager();
            myViewpager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManag, false));
            myViewpager.setCurrentItem(200);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // montly or total
        if (group == radioGroup1) {
            switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radioButton1:
                rG1 = false;
                rgCheck();
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                rG1 = true;
                rgCheck();
                break;
            }
        }
        // show all or show by cat
        if (group == radioGroup2) {
            // false : showAll True: show by category
            switch (checkedId) {
            // show all
            case R.id.rg2radioButton1:
                rG2 = false;
                rgCheck();
                break;
            // show by cat
            case R.id.rg2radioButton2:
                rG2 = true;
                rgCheck();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // TODO checking for radio group
    public void rgCheck() {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragManag = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (!rG2) {
                myViewpager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManag, false));
                myViewpager.setCurrentItem(200);
            } else {

                myViewpager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(fragManag, true));
                myViewpager.setCurrentItem(200);
            }

    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        boolean radioGroup2Track;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, boolean rG) {
            super(fm);
            this.radioGroup2Track = rG;
        }

        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment frag = null;
            frag = FragmentMoneyMontly.newInstance(position - 200, radioGroup2Track);
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 401;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            for (int i = 0; i < 199; i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i - 200);
                    return (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                }
            }

            if (position == 199) {
                return "Prev Month";
            }
            // show today month
            if (position == 200) {
                return "This Month";
            }

            if (position == 201) {
                return "Next Month";
            }
            // Show next month
            for (int i = 202; i <= 400; i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i - 200);
                    return (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code for fragment inside the View Group :

```
public class FragmentMoneyMontly extends Fragment {
    private static final String TEXT_AT_END = "Total : ";
    ListView transactionListV;
    TextView totalMontlyTV;
    int dateposition = 0;

    public static FragmentMoneyMontly newInstance(int index, boolean radioGTrack) {
        FragmentMoneyMontly f = new FragmentMoneyMontly();
        // Supply index, radioTrack input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        args.putBoolean("radioGtrack", radioGTrack);
        f.setArguments(args);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_money_manager, container, false);

        transactionListV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.transactionData1);
        totalMontlyTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.totalMontly);
        HulkDataBaseAdapter db = new HulkDataBaseAdapter(getActivity());

        // getting from new instance method
        dateposition = getArguments().getInt("index", -1000);
        boolean rgTrack = getArguments().getBoolean("radioGtrack", false);

        // error checking
        if (dateposition == -1000) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            setDateListView(db, rgTrack);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void setTextView() {

    }

    public void setDateListView(HulkDataBaseAdapter db, boolean rgTrack) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        for (int i = -200; i < 0; i++) {
            if (dateposition == i) {
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);

                String monthString = String.format("%02d", (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
                String yearString = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                showListView(monthString, yearString, db, rgTrack);
            }
        }
        // show today month
        if (dateposition == 0) {
            String currentMonth = String.format("%02d", cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            String currentYear = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            showListView(currentMonth, currentYear, db, rgTrack);
        }
        // Show next month
        for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
            if (dateposition == i) {
                cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, i);
                String monthString = String.format("%02d", (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
                String yearString = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                showListView(monthString, yearString, db, rgTrack);
            }
        }
    }

    public void showListView(String currentMonth, String currentYear, HulkDataBaseAdapter db, boolean rgTrack) {
        // init
        String[] catArray = null;
        String[] amountArray = null;
        boolean[] expenseArray = null;
        int currCount = db.selectCatFromDate(currentMonth, currentYear).length;
        // if DB is not empty
        if (currCount != 0) {
            // ADD count to amount and disply it in TextView
            int countAmount = 0;
            // Show each individual (based on RadioGroup)
            if (rgTrack == false) {
                // initialization
                catArray = new String[currCount];
                amountArray = new String[currCount];
                expenseArray = new boolean[currCount];
                // set cat amount expanse to array
                for (int i = 0, c = currCount; i < currCount; i++) {
                    // Show it in reverse (last item first)
                    String catThis = db.selectCatFromDate(currentMonth, currentYear)[i];
                    int amountInt = db.selectAmountFromDate(currentMonth, currentYear)[i];
                    boolean expenseThis = db.selectExpenseFromDate(currentMonth, currentYear)[i];
                    String amountThis;
                    if (expenseThis) {
                        amountInt = amountInt * (-1);
                        countAmount -= amountInt;
                        amountThis = String.valueOf(amountInt);
                    } else {
                        countAmount += amountInt;
                        amountThis = "+"+String.valueOf(amountInt);
                    }

                    // saving in reverse format
                    c--;
                    catArray[c] = catThis;
                    amountArray[c] = amountThis;
                    expenseArray[c] = expenseThis;
                }

                // set the adapter and show it
                CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), catArray, amountArray, expenseArray);
                transactionListV.setAdapter(adapter);
                // show count to textview text: Total : x $
                String textCountAll = TEXT_AT_END + countAmount + MoneyManager.DOLLAR;
                totalMontlyTV.setText(textCountAll);
            }

            // Show by Category (based on RadioGroup)
            else {
                String[] catAllArray = db.selectAllCategoryTable();
                int countCat = catAllArray.length;
                String[] amountAllArray = new String[countCat];
                boolean[] expenseAllArray = new boolean[countCat];
                for (int i = 0; i < countCat; i++) {
                    int ThisAmount = db.totalAmountOfCatFromDateCategoryTable(catAllArray[i], currentMonth, currentYear);
                    countAmount += ThisAmount;
                    if (ThisAmount < 0){
                        expenseAllArray[i] = true;
                        amountAllArray[i] = String.valueOf(ThisAmount);
                    }
                    else {
                        expenseAllArray[i] = false;
                        amountAllArray[i] = "+"+String.valueOf(ThisAmount);
                    }
                }

                CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), catAllArray, amountAllArray, expenseAllArray);
                transactionListV.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            String textCountAll = TEXT_AT_END + countAmount + MoneyManager.DOLLAR;
            totalMontlyTV.setText(textCountAll);
        }
        // if Transaction DB is empty
        else {
            String[] noString = { MoneyManager.NOTHING };
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNo = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, noString);
            transactionListV.setAdapter(adapterNo);
        }
    }
}

// Custom adapter for List View
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    String[] categoryArray;
    String[] amountArray;
    boolean[] expanseB;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, String[] categoty, String[] amount, boolean[] expanse) {
        super(c, R.layout.list_view_in_money_manager, R.id.textView1x, categoty);
        this.context = c;
        this.amountArray = amount;
        this.categoryArray = categoty;
        this.expanseB = expanse;
    }

    int count = 0;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_in_money_manager, parent, false);
        }

        TextView category = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1x);
        TextView amount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2x);

        category.setText(categoryArray[position]);
        amount.setText(amountArray[position] + MoneyManager.DOLLAR);

        if (expanseB[position]) {
            amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFF4444"));
        } else {
            amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"));
        }
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not strange its expected behavior when orientation is changed onCreate gets called. You can use onSaveInstaceState to save your Data i.e attached to adapter and then onRestoreInstanceState set the adapter again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when u rotate ur screen the activity is destroyed and restarts again

Comment: I know it but it was quiet strange that it didn't destroy for first time

Comment: try putting ur code in onResumeMethod() or save chaneges using onSaveInstanceState

Answer (score 3):

How about adding **android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard"** in your **activity tag** inside **androidmanifest.xml**
it will never recreate your view even changed your orientation you dont want to manage any instance management. If you want to do some task during orientation change you can override onConfigurationChanged() in your activity

Comment: I tried this but this code will remove my land-orientation which I designed in res/layout-land for some reason!