# ListView disappears upon screen rotation

Tags: android, listview, screen-orientation

I have a problem with screen rotation.
I have a ListView with data.
Everytime I rotate the screen, the ListView disappears.
I tried this in the Class which contains the ListView.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    loadActivity();
}
```

I have also put this in the manifest

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Still nothing.

Any help would be appreciated and earn a big green tick

```
private void loadActivity() {
    // Do all of your work here
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    getData();//get business email
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    txt.setText(email);


}
```

Comment: Are you using two different layout files for this activity ? (one for portrait and one for landscape)

Comment: what does this loadActivity do ?

Comment: he load activity loads the list from database

Comment: can you please share the loadActivity code ?

Comment: private void loadActivity() {
        // Do all of your work here
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        getData();//get business email
        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
        txt.setText(email);


    }

Comment: @zed please comment out this line loadActivity() inside onConfig change and called this loadActivity method inside onCreate Method of Activity It will work

Comment: i tried that it still not happening :/

Comment: @zed can you share your code if possible

Comment: The standard default behaviour in Android is to kill your `Activity` and recreate it on a screen orientation change. Since you've added `android:configChanges` to your manifest, Android won't do that, but instead it will call `onConfigurationChanged()` instead. You should ty to use the standard behaviour unless you have a good reason not to. What happens when you remove the `android:configChanges` from your manifest?

Comment: i'm unable to share my  code unfortantely ,and david nothing happens still same thing

Comment: Is your `Activity` getting recreated? Add logging to `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` to see.

Comment: Could we see `getData()` and its callback ? As far as the code you posted is concerned, you never set an adapter.

Comment: yes it is i can see other data such as values i passed from previous activity which i have set to a textview in that activity but the listview is not being recreated although if i change it to normal orientation it will reappear..

Comment: i don't need an adapter i'm  adding  the values straight from json form into the listview

Comment: i have an adapter in the showlist () which is setting the values from json form to the list

Comment: ok, something is really way off. maybe you could post at least a stripped down version of your code ?

Comment: Ok but the problem is not with the listview ,the listview is working  and when i call get data  the json is parsed and the showlist method is called this is where im adding my json values to the list and showing the list ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange bug when i rotate the screen the listview inside of viewpager will disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128107/strange-bug-when-i-rotate-the-screen-the-listview-inside-of-viewpager-will-disap)

Answer (score 0):

Jitty's answer on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128107/strange-bug-when-i-rotate-the-screen-the-listview-inside-of-viewpager-will-disap) worked for me:
Add `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|keyboard"` to your activity tag in AndroidManafest.xml